# How to subset a vector, based on the condition "contains" a character?

Tags: r, extract, wildcard, subset, contains

If I have a vector:

```
Months = month.abb[1:12]
```

I want to extract all the months that start with Letter J (in this case, Jan, Jun, and Jul).

1. Is there a wildcard character, like * in Excel, which lists all elements of vectors which you search for J*?
2. How do I extract elements that start with either letter 'M' or 'A'. The expected output would be Mar,May,Apr,Aug?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
 grep("^J", Months,value=TRUE)
 #[1] "Jan" "Jun" "Jul"

grep("^A|^M", Months,value=TRUE)
#[1] "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Aug"
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked absolutely flawless. Cheers mate !

Answer (score 2):

You'll find the `glob2rx` function helpful for converting wildcard constructions to regular expressions:

```
> glob2rx("J*")
[1] "^J"
> grep(glob2rx("J*"), Months, value=TRUE)
[1] "Jan" "Jun" "Jul"
```

Comment: Thank you for bringing glob2rx to our attention.  Are there other tools in base R that help people create regexes correctly?

Comment: @user2583119 There aren't any other similar functions that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have `stringr` loaded you could do:

```
library(stringr)

str_subset(Months, "^J")
[1] "Jan" "Jun" "Jul"
```